# Command line argument: Segmentation fault

Tags: command-line

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

printf("Write in this format: <operand1> <operator> <operand2>\n");
double result, op1, op2;

op1 = atof(argv[1]);
op2 = atof(argv[3]);

if(argv[2][0]=='+')
    result = op1 + op2;
if(argv[2][0]=='-')
    result = op1 - op2;
if(argv[2][0]=='/')
    result = op1 / op2;
if(argv[2][0]=='x')
    result = op1 * op2;

printf("Result: %f", result);

return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to make this work but it's causing a Segmentation fault. I've checked my code and I just can't find anything wrong with it. It's supposed to work like a simple calculator. And then I tried the man page for argv or argc and it says, "No manual entry for..." something like that. I mean, isn't there supposed to be one? Or do I have to update something?
I'd appreciate it if anyone would reply whatever he/she think/s that can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that this post is off-topic, but I'll help you anyway. What is the command that call to your program into your question? Why are you using `argv[2][0]` instead of `argv[2]`? Are you sure that your `atof()` function is **working**?

Comment: Oh, stupid me. It's supposed to be 2. It's working now. Thanks!

Comment: This looks like C, not command line arguments to me. This MAY have been better asked on SO, I don't see anything to do with ubuntu at all here

Answer (score 1):

Your code have a syntaxis/concept error in the four conditionals.

You are requesting `argv[2][0]` but it should be `argv[2]` instead:

- `argv[2][0]` means: the position cero of a pointer to char (bad) in the third position in the array
- `argv[2]` means: the content of the pointer to char that is in the third position in the array

That is why you get the [Segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) error.